# Selenium IDE: How to verify <TD> Contents when it contains a mix of tags and <BR> breaks

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide, newline

My goal is to verify the contents of a complicated TD cell. It contains a SPAN tage and many BR tags. I'm restricted to using Selenium IDE for this test. The source text looks like this:

```
<td>
 <span><b style="whatever">TEXT_1</b></span> 
 <br style="whatever">
  TEXT_2
 <br style="whatever">
  TEXT_3
 <br>
</td>
```

Neither TEXT_1 / TEXT_2 / TEXT_3 contain any spaces.

I pull the TD contents into the variable 'td_cell_contents'. Then Javascript is used to split that variable on a single space:

```
store | javascript{storedVars['td_cell_contents'].split(' ')[0]} | var_1
store | javascript{storedVars['td_cell_contents'].split(' ')[1]} | var_2
```

var_1 evaluates to "TEXT_1" as I would expect because there's a space between it and the rest of the cell.
When I echo var_2, the log file shows that that is a new line between "TEXT_2" and "TEXT_3" as I would expect since there is a BR tag between them:

```
[info] echo: var_2: TEXT 2
TEXT 3
```

I tried to use JavaScript to strip the newlines because this newline is making strong comparison very difficult:

```
runScript | var_2 = var_2.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />'); |
```

When I run the echo command again for var_2, the log shows that the newline is still there. It's blocking the ability to do string matching.

Looking for help... and am open to using other approaches within Selenium IDE. If I can verify the cell contents somehow without stripping the newline that's fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions in answering this question. It sounds like your goal is to validate the contents of var_2. Stripping out the newline is a means to an end. There are other ways to accomplish this though.

Why don't you try to create a variable called "expected_var_2_value", and set it equal to the expected var_2 string WITHOUT the newline stripped out as follows:

```
store | TEXT_2\nTEXT_3 | expected_var_2_value
```

Then just compare it to var_2:

```
verifyEval | storedVars['expected_var_2_value']==storedVars['var_2'] | true
```

For some reason the Javascript in the verifyEval works for me when comparing storedVars['expected_var_2_value'] but fails if the actual underlying string is provided.

Anyway, I would appreciate feedback on how this goes for you.